# Solution to Riccati differential equation using transformations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this Riccati differential equation?

$$\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{-a}{2(bx-x^3)}-\frac{y^
2(bx-x^3)}{(a^2)}$$

Where $a, b $ are real constants.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation has the form $y'+py^2=q$. The transformation is in this case $y=\frac{u'}{pu}$. Alternatively $y=\frac{qv}{v'}$ can be used. Continuing with the first variant
$$
\frac{u''}{pu}-\frac{p'u'}{p^2u}-\frac{u'^2}{pu^2}+p\frac{u'^2}{p^2u^2}=q,
$$
so that then without fractions
$$
u''-\frac{p'}{p}u'=pqu.
$$
Now insert $p=\frac{bx-x^3}{a^2}$ and $q=-\frac{a}{bx-x^3}$ to get
$$
u''-\frac{b-3x^2}{bx-x^3}u'+\frac1au=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you@Lutz Lehmann. How to solve the tranformed second order ODE? Can you please explain.

Comment: The second order equation can be easier to solve as power series and numerically, especially around poles. As for the symbolic solution, sometimes one can see something obvious in this form, but in general what looks impossible in one form will also look impossible in the other form. If you for some reason expect an easily solvable problem after transformation, then check again the solution as seen here but more importantly the equation in the question and how you got to it.

Comment: Well, as for numerical solutions it is possible and I did it. But I was looking for analytical solution, but I tried to solve it symbolically using Matlab, Python and Mathematica but it said no explicit solution available. However as you have said we should be able to expand solution as power series  around regular singular points, this transformed second order ODE has three regular singular points. The solution should have Hypergeometric function as said here. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function